# hadoop fs -text returns InvocationTargetException

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to read a file with `hadoop fs -text`. The file is a sequence file defined in my own classes - for that I am using parameter `-libjars`. Normally. This time I am getting InvocationTargetException with no stacktrace:

```
# hadoop fs -libjars myjar.jar -text /tmp/part-r-00000
12/09/21 17:24:18 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library is available
12/09/21 17:24:18 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
12/09/21 17:24:18 INFO snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library loaded
text: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

It is hard to see what is going on.

Comment: Did you try reading the seq. file by issuing `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/path_to/myjar.jar:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH; hadoop fs -text /tmp/part-r-00000` instead?

Comment: well, from the logs you have it's hard to determine the root of the problem therefore I suggested some hints in my answer that may probably help you to get further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something to do with nested classes or dependencies classes in your Key / Value class.

the `-libjars` option when used the FsShell (`hadoop fs`) adds your jar to the classpath (as you'd expect), so your root Key / Value class is now available. What is probably happening here is your Key / Value class depends on another class either not in the jar listed in libjars, or is in a nested jar (in the libs folder in the jar).

This is made confusing by the fact the `hadoop jar` command will unpack you jar and add all the nested jars in the lib folder to the classpath when it submits a job, but the FsShell command does not unpack the jar.

Annoyingly the FsShell doesn't dump full stack traces to stderr, but if you enable debug level logging you should see the full stack trace (not sure how you do this though)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if you get `text: [null|classname|exception]` instead of the content of the file then most probably `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell` throws an Exception somewhere.

If you have the opportunity, run Hadoop in *local mode* and *debug* that class when reading
the seq. file from command line.

In `FsShell` I'd set breakpoints at the these places:

```
 public int read() throws IOException {
   ...
 }
```

and

```
 public TextRecordInputStream(FileStatus f) throws IOException {
   ...
 }
```

Check also the serialization/deserialization process of your custom `Writable` since a bug  during the deserialization can cause such problems.